# What does the word 「してやせんっ」 mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, particle-は, renyōkei

I have come across the word in a manga. It is said by a boy who was talking about the future plan of selling prizes awarded from playing Pachinko.

Here is the sentence including the word:

> いつまでも　たたき売{う}りなんぞ**してやせんっ**。

I'm not sure if the word is related to the word 痩{や}せる.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with 「[痩]{や}せる」(= to become slimmer); That is for sure.

「してやせん」＝「して + や + せん」

「して」, needless to say, is the て-form of 「する」.

「や」 is a colloquial (or regional) pronunciation of 「は」.

See here: [大辞林 「や（係助）口頭語で、係助詞『は』がなまったもの。『誰も[来]{き}やしない（こやしない）』『霧で何も見えやしない』」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84-647430#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) (Toward the bottom of the page)

「せん」 means 「しない」.

「～～して**や**せん」＝「～～して**は**いない」 = "would/will not be doing ~~", "am not doing ~~", etc.

Other examples with the same structure:

> 「[誰]{だれ}も[食]{た}べ**や**せん！」＝「誰も食べ**は**しない！」 = "No one will eat it!"
>
> 「[車]{くるま}なんか[買]{か}え**や**せん！」＝「車なんか買え**は**しない」 = "There is no way I could afford a car!"

Comment: I agree that this is correct if the boy is not speaking politely. Though I feel negating する itself using する in this way is not common.

Comment: Maybe there should have been a reference to difference of intonation between してはせん and してません.

Comment: You said「～～してやせん」＝「～～してはいない」. I'm not sure this is right. I think 「～～してやせん」 uses the pattern <masu-stem>+はしない:

「～～してやせん」＝「～～してる」＋「はしない」＝「～～してはしない」

Comment: してはしない? I get RYK+はしない, but not -て+はしない.

Comment: `「して」, needless to say, is the 連用形 of 「する」` ん？「し」が「する」の連用形で、「て」は接続助詞ちゃう？　勝手に「て形」に変えたらアカンやろか？

Comment: しらんねん、文法とか。コワいわあ、チャットルームのエキスパートたち・・

Answer (score 5):

ま is sometimes replaced with や:

> - もうしわけありやせん （もうしわけありません）
> - ありがとうございやす （ありがとうございます）
> - 元気でありやす （元気であります）

If that's the case with your example, that part simply means してません.

I'm not sure if this is a real dialect spoken somewhere, or it's a kind of slurred speech not particularly associated with a certain dialect.

Comment: Completely disagreed.  Typing my own answer.

Comment: 「してはせん」（→する気はない）と解釈する方かな。この人の普段のしゃべり方によってはそっちかも。