# What is the meaning of this ては

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

This a part of the song "Donut hole" by hachi

```
何も知らないままでいるのが   
あなたを傷つけてはしないか
```

I asked a japanese person and they told me it's similar to `あなたを傷つけるのではないだろうか`. However I don't understand how it works grammatically. As far as I know the は particle cannot topicalize verbs in the TE FORM.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%82%84%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%a3-mean/24666#24666 - related, but I'm not entirely willing to say duplicate because of some remaining confusion

Comment: @Angelos It is indeed the same question, but that person seems to have arbitrarily claimed that 連用形+は+しない is the same thing as て+は+しない without any further explanation. I guess I could take that for now.

Comment: 傷つけてはしないか makes no sense to me. 傷つけてはいないか does.

Comment: Well, that is what is sung. It`s very clear and there are subtitles. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct_YOfxc7Hw

Comment: It still makes no sense. I was not suggesting it was your error.

Comment: Oh, I see. It does not really make any sense to me too. I suppose it's something that Japanese speakers might say thinking is correct (???). My take is that since テ形 can be used as conjunction like 連用形 due to 中止法, they might wrongly say てはしない with the meaning of 連用形＋は＋しない aka 傷つけはしない. Yet, I'd like someone to confirm this. I have no other ideas though.

Comment: @aguijonazo Two native speakers in the question I linked(nartuo and l'électeur [now user4032]) seem to have no trouble interpreting ～てはしない as a variant of ～（連用形）はしない, so saying it makes no sense seems a bit forceful.

Comment: @Angelos - The linked question is about a dialectal phrase that ends with 〜やせん. I have little trouble understanding it. This one is different. It makes no sense to me, and I have no idea why they didn’t correct it before they published the song. I found two related questions on HiNative ([食べない と 食べてはしない はどう違いますか？](https://ja.hinative.com/questions/2478696) and [What does 気つけてはしない (てはしないってどういう意味？) mean?](https://hinative.com/questions/2478739)). Natives there say “we don’t say that.”

Comment: @Angelos - And only one person, by the name of Axe, brought up 〜してはしない in the linked question, not l'électeur or naruto.

Comment: Axe was the only one to bring up the topic in the comments, but user4032 mentioned it in his answer as if both patterns were the same. @aguijonazo. But he did it without further explanation.

Comment: l'électeur (user4032) said ～してやせん was the same as ～してはいない. As I said, the former is a dialect. や may be は and せん by itself does mean しない, but it doesn’t necessarily mean ～してやせん equals ～してはしない. You cannot understand the nuance of a dialect by translating it into standard language portion by portion like that. ～してはしない is not a valid form.

Comment: He indeed says as they were the same indirectly:「誰も食べやせん！」＝「誰も食べはしない！」 = "No one will eat it!". With the topic of "other examples with the same structure"

Comment: That 食べやせん corresponds to 食べはしない doesn’t mean 食べ**て**やせん corresponds to 食べ**て**はしない, which is not a valid form anyway.

Comment: Although I agree with you that 食べてはしない is an odd sentence, I don't think it is wrong. I don't think Hachi aka Kenshi Yonezu would release a song with wrong lyrics. I also don't think it is for poetic reasons because the rest of the song is very ok. Asking 傷つけてはいないか and 傷つけはしないか (assuming that 食べてはしない means the same as 食べはしない) result in really similar questions that use the は topicalizing function. With the assumption that it is not wrong, I think the meaning should probably be what I said before "wrong grammar trying to say something else". I think calling it not valid is a bit forceful.

Comment: Missing the distinction between 〜しは**し**ない and 〜し**て**は**い**ない is missing the distinction between する and している. This mixed-up 〜してしない destroys this crucial distinction. Some might call it "creative destruction". I don't.

Comment: しはしない and してはいない are not being mixed. I just gave examples to show that the meaning is similar and should probably be around that spectrum of meaning. The thing is that てはしない / しはしない seem to be related. It's not something out of nowhere like I explained before (the 中止法 thing). Aside from that, language is a living thing and evolves regardless of people's will.

Comment: I’m a native and I would never recognize 〜してはしない as a variation of 〜しはしない. It’s closer to 〜してはいない because of て. That’s how I would understand it if I need to make some sense out of it.

Comment: I appreciate your point of view but, in my opinion, since it's a pseudo-correct grammar, it's  not really **more **correct to think of it as a variation of  てはいない because of て instead of しはしない because of し. That's at least what my Japanese friend told me. Anyway, I think you should consider making your point of view an answer for posterity in case someone in the future questions that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence was probably made by two steps.

Firstly, why we use 傷つけ**ては**いないか,not 傷つけていないか. Because ”ては” can emphasis the sentence.

Secondly, why Yonezu uses 傷つけては**しないか**,not 傷つけてはいないか. This is difficult problem. Although I'm Japanese, I think this expression is a little wrong. But, I guess he wants to give us to a little weird feeling.

I translate them forcibly, あなたを傷つけていないか means ”Am I hurting you?”, あなたを傷つけてはいないか means ”Am I even hurting you?”, あなたを傷つけてはしないか means ”Do I even hurting you?”.

Comment: I agree with you. I also think he was trying to be a little poetic and forceful. Thank you.

Comment: I found another Vocaloid song that uses it, ラジオスターが消えたって by 皮肉骨. It has the following verse:

失ってはしないか　何かを
そんな不安が　頭を喰う